# What's up with Neural Stochastic Differential Equations from a practical standpoint?

Tags: papers, deep-neural-networks, applications

I've spent a few days reading some of the new papers about Neural SDEs. For example, [here is one from Tzen and Raginsky](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.09883) and [here is one that came out simultaneously by Peluchetti and Favaro](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11065). There are others which I plan to read next. The basic idea, which are attained via different routes in each paper, is that if we consider the input data arriving at time $t=0$ and the output data arriving at time $t=1$, and with certain assumptions on the distribution of network weights and activations, the evolution of the data from one layer to the next inside the network is akin to a stochastic process. The more layers you have, the smaller the $\Delta t$ is between the layers. In the limit as the number of layers goes to infinity, the network approaches a true stochastic differential equation.

I am still working on the math, which is my main objective. However, what I find missing from these papers is: ***Why is this important?*** The question is not, *why is this interesting?*. It is certainly interesting from a purely mathematical perspective. But what is the importance here? What is the impact of this technology?

I was at first excited about this because I thought it proposed a way to apply a neural network to learn the the parameters of an SDE by fitting it to real time-series data where we don't know the form of the underlying data generation process. However I noticed in the experiment of Peluchetti and Favaro is simply the MNIST data set, while the data experiment from Tzen and Raginsky is in fact a simulated SDE. The later fit more with my intuition.

So, again, my question is, what is the general importance of Neural SDEs? And a secondary question is: am I correct in thinking this technology proposes a new way to fit a model to data which we suppose is generated by a stochastic process?